# Replace URL String with Integer characters located in the end of that String

Tags: java, regex, android-studio

I have some URL link and tried to replace all non-integer values with integers in the end of the link using regex

The URL is something like

```
https://some.storage.com/test123456.bucket.com/folder/80.png
```

Regex i tried to use:

```
Integer.parseInt(string.replaceAll(".*[^\\d](\\d+)", "$1"))
```

Output for that regex is "80.png", and i need only "80". Also i tried this tool - https://regex101.com. And as i see the main problem is that ".png" not matching with my regex and then, after substitution, this part adding to matching group.

I'm totally noob in regex, so i kindly ask you for help.

Comment: `string.replaceAll(".*\\D(\\d+).*", "$1")`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sjNVck/2)

Comment: Is the pattern of your urls always ending with digits followed by non digits?

Comment: Yes, dryleaf, it is

Comment: See my answer below with a much enhanced solution version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String result = string.replaceAll("(?:.*\\D)?(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/soQBKZ/1).

**NOTE**: If there is no match, the `result` will be equal to the `string` value. If you do not want this behavior, instead of `"(?:.*\\D)?(\\d+).*"`, use `"(?:.*\\D)?(\\d+).*|.+"`.

**Details**

- `(?:.*\D)?` - an optional (it must be optional because the Group 1 pattern might also be matched at the start of the string) sequence of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\D` - a non-digit
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: any one or more digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

The replacement is `$1`, the backreference to Group 1 value, actually, the last 1+ digit chunk in the string that has no line breaks.

Line breaks can be supported if you prepend the pattern with the `(?s)` inline DOTALL modifier, i.e. `"(?s)(?:.*\\D)?(\\d+).*|.+"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, @Wiktor Stribiżew :)